# Magento addin for Related Categories, similar to Related Products

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I'm looking for a Magento addin that replaces Related Products with Related Categories.

I maintain a Magento site which sells inspirational merchandise. People often arrive at the site and see something they like, but not completely. For example, they may see a paperweight with a quotation they like, but they want a baseball cap with the same quotation. Or, the may like the paperweight but want a different quotation on it. Products are all categorized & sub-categorized on the site, but many shoppers just hit Back if they don't see an obvious & easy way to get exactly what they want.

I want to automatically place a box on the right side of each product page (much like Related Products) which lists links to several category pages, instead of individual products (there are too many). For example, you'd have automatically-generated links like "Other products with the same quotation," "Other products with the same design," etc.  I'd be OK if the categories listed were either all of the categories the product belongs to, or a list that the admin can manually create fore each product.

Also, I said category, but it'd be ok if this worked on keywords/phrases, attributes, or something like that -- whatever's out there.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered making use of product tags as associations?

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this question?

Answer (score 0):

One way that you can achieve this is to adapt your Related Products block to show only the categories of the related products that have been assigned, not the products themselves.

For instance, if you have related products of 'Apples' (in fruit), 'Bagels' (in bread) and 'Cucumbers' (in vegetables) then you need not show 'Apples/Bagels/Cucumbers' and instead you could show 'Fruit/Bread/Vegetables'.

I have not checked how you can the master category for each of the related products, you may need to add that to the collection for it to show up in the template.

The advantage of this technique is that you can theme up the related products and not have to write a complicated module.